Could an azhdarchid pterosaur take off and fly while being ridden by a human?
Could humans theoretically ride any of the largest azhdarchid pterosaurs, assuuming a wingspan of about 10.5m and weight of about 200-250kg for the largest azhdarchids such as Hatzegopteryz or Quetzalcoatlus (taken from Mark Witton's 2013 book Pterosaurs, so some numbers may have been revised since then). For what its worth, my setting has a slightly thicker atmosphere, mostly around 1.5atm and up to 2atm in places.
Its generally assumed that they specialize in soaring flight, so aside from the extra weight and some drag a theoretical rider shouldn't interfere with that too much. The main issue would be the quadrupedal launch (and landing) and occasional powered flight.
Witton briefly discusses the possibility of water launches, suggesting that while azhdarchids preferred solid ground, they had more than enough power to take off from the water in a series of hops or even in one big thrust. This would seem to imply that they would be able to support the added energetic cost and biomechanical loading of the extra weight of a human.
If this wouldn't be possible, what traits would a breeding program need to accentuate to make this easier? Even if it is possible, what traits would be most important to accentuate over time to improve rideability, like in horse domestication?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

(a) You're allowed to ask one and only one question. You're asking two regardless the yes/no condition (can it be done? yes/no. Conditions (regardless yes/no)?) (b) We think we know about those dinosaurs, but it's a lot of extrapolations based on precious little data, which means the [tag:science-based] tag is a tall order. All we have are theories about how they could fly, which isn't science because science requires repeatable experimentation or observation which isn't possible in this case. (c) Beside all that, we're here to help you build a fictional ... (*Continued*)

... world. We permit real-world questions, but those questions should have relevance to your fictional world. A proper question to ask here is, "I want humans to fly on the back of azhdarchid pterosaurs, what characteristics of a breeding program would rationalize this?" Of course, the next comment would be, "what aspects of horse domestication doesn't answer your question?" and that would be a reasonable concern.

You may find some frame challenge style answers to your question here and here and also here .. the frame challenge is that you may not need any selective breading, that some pterosaurs may be fully large enough as they are.

the hardest part os take off, they need to be able to jump high enough to for the first flight stroke. so extect eleveted takeoff points whenever possible.

My first instinct on this was a solid “no.” However, after looking into it more, it seems there’s a slim, very conditional possibility that riding an azhdarchid pterosaur could happen.
There’s an interview with a paleontologist, Dr. Elizabeth G. Martin-Silverstone, where she critiques three potential saddle designs for an azhdarchid pterosaur: One with an upright seat, one strapped to the belly, and one with the rider lying flat. Only the last one, inspired by the Skybax riders in James Gurney’s Dinotopia series, had a chance of working. The animation on the video shows the rider's feet bouncing around, but if you look closely at Gurney's design, it has stirrups to keep the feet still. This is essential since Dr. Martin-Silverstone says pterosaur bones could easily fracture with hard, direct hits like a punch or flailing heels.
Now the big caveat is that even with the best saddle design, Dr. Martin-Silverstone still believes that an adult human would be too heavy. She does think a child might be able to fly but doesn’t specify what age or size of child. The video shows the weight for an adult human male as 84 kg/ 185 lbs, so I would think you’d want to cap rider weight around at least half of that, 42 kg/ 93 lbs. That’s within the average healthy range for children aged 9-10, and lighter even than the more restrictive end of the weight limits for jockeys in horse racing, 112 lbs (50.8 kg).
Regarding the idea of breeding, I don’t think that would help. If you managed to breed pterosaurs 84 kg lighter, they’d probably lose muscle mass or wingspan since there’s nothing extra to cut. Their bones are already hollow, they have air sacs everywhere, and the currently favored theory of quadrupedal launch means that they can even do without the heavy leg muscles of birds.
Adapting the humans might work better, but I’d need to know more about the why and where of this scenario. Does whatever they’re doing with the pterosaurs require adulthood? Warfare is one thing that probably wouldn’t work even with child riders since weapons add weight and pterosaurs are easily broken. Also, since you mention a thicker atmosphere, I’m wondering whether this means that the humans could have co-evolved with their pterosaurs to be lighter. There's a lot more extra weight that could be trimmed off the humans compared to the pterosaurs. If your setting does require unmodified humans, though, you're likely to end up with children or unusually small adults as your riders.

Welcome to the site Yeslek. Nice first answer.

This answer reminded me of the 588th Night Bomber Regiment.

@Escaped - Thanks! This is the site that first attracted me to Stack Exchange, so I'm really glad I could put my interest in prehistoric creatures to use here.

Thanks for the answer! I haven't though much about modifying the humans yet, but the setting could allow for it. Its a generally hard science setting, with solar-system-spanning high-tech human civilization(s) that have since fractured and collapsed. I'm still working out how much those civs played with human genome editing and how much variation would remain in later human pops, but there could definitely be more range and variation in any number of traits. I'm still working on a timeline, but it'll be pretty long and there are lots of islands so insular dwarfism is also a possibility..(cont)

(continued) The people start with very little technology, and would have to domesticate everything from scratch (this question origionally came out of wondering if i could replace dogs with pterosaurs, which is a whole seperate issue). It would seem tough to make progress in the azhdarchid domestication process while simultaneously becoming more bite-sized.

If you were imagining them replacing dogs, I wonder if domestication could have started out with the pterosaurs as hunting/fishing partners, sort of like huge cormorants. Riding might come later.

I suppose the biggest problem wouldn't be the added weight, but the non aerodynamic shape of humans, if we were on a vertical position either on the back or on the belly I think it may be possible, I even read about it some time in the past and I apologize for not finding the source of the study, but it said that the estimated size for the largest pterosaur wasn't even close to their theoretical limit.
In a sense it does makes sense, the biggest fossil we found of a pterosaur isn't the biggest pterosaur that ever existed, Quetzalcoatlus northopi for exemple is known for a dozen of bones from six individuals, we can't assume the largest of this set represents the largest of them all, just like if Blue whales were extinct, it's statistically implausible we would find fossils of the largest ones that ever existed.
The point I'm trying to reach is that even if a 10.5m wide wingspan pterosaur can't lift an adult human, a bigger one can.
